# Parse string as a html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parser

I have a HTML tag as a string comes from controller.. I need to parse it in html..The code is like ,

```
var str = '<span id="c.s.y"></span> Y <span id="c.s.m"></span> M';
var parsed = $.parseHTML(str);
```

This parsed string into html.. but I have to append some text before each seperate tag..I fetch each tag as,

```
$.each( parsed , function( i, el ) { console.log("asd" + el + "asd"); });
```

I cann't append text in each tag here it shows `[object HTMLSpanElement]
[object Text]` .. how to append text here..
I want output as a
`asd <span id="c.s.y"></span> asd
asd Y asd
asd <span id="c.s.m"></span> asd
asd N asd`

Comment: Could you please give an example of the output you're expecting to see

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan updated the question

Comment: Add `.toString()`?

Comment: tried but it shows `[object HTMLSpanElement]` @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable

Comment: What exactly you want to do? `console.log` element or work with this element?

Comment: I have to work with that element.. this was code what I was trying in devtool.. @DenisSheremet

Comment: If you remove the `M` at the end, you can use `parsed[0].outerHTML` to get the string.
If you put _any_ HTML element around the text, you can use `parsed[0].innerHTML` to get everything except the outer element.

Comment: I can't remove anything from string..this is string which I have to convert in html as it is..

Comment: The problem is that you are using concatenation (+) to add text, when once parsed, you want to manipulate elements. You'll need to use `insert`, `insertBefore` or `prepend` instead

Comment: You mean like `el.prepend('asda')` @jcaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML elements you could use `outerHTML` property

```
$.each(parsed, function(i, el) {
var $el = $(el);
if ($el.prop('outerHTML'))
    console.log("asd" + $el.prop('outerHTML') + "asd"); 
else
    console.log("asd" + $el.text() + "asd");
});
```

Comment: yeah, but does it matter? are you gonna process it later on?

Answer (score 0):

To get your html into something you can work with, use this:

```
$("<div/>").html(txt);
```

eg, in your case:

```
var str = '<span id="c.s.y"></span> Y <span id="c.s.m"></span> M';
var parsed = $("<div/>").html(str);
```

you then have 'parsed' as a 'normal' jquery object which you can manipulate as required, eg:

```
parsed.find("*").wrap("<span>");
parsed.contents().wrap("<span>");
$("#myid").append(parsed);
```

As `.wrap()` applies tags, in your case, you'll need to use `.append` and `.prepend`, something like:

```
parsed.find("*").andSelf().append(" asd ").prepend(" asd ");
```

Comment: It doesn't wrap text in html

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "wrap text in html".  If you want the text elements, use `.contents()`.   Manipulate as required - the question was *how to parse a string as html* and *append some text before each seperate **tag*** - nothing about wrapping text.